# I want to access full features of instagram API before go live

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I want to access full features of Instagram API before go live. I am in the last phase of testing and if I submit a permission request will it be accepted? My website url will not be the same as live one as I have not migrated yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get full API access without getting permission review, You will be approved in sandbox mode as long as you show video screencast of ALL API usage in app.

All apps currently approved were reviewed with limited sandbox mode access, you may be able to get away without migrating to actual website, your video screencast should show all login flow and app fuctionality for all APIs and must be clear as to what your app is trying to achieve